# Is there a way to respond with bad request during controller initialization or smth similar

Tags: asp.net-core

```
public abstract class AbstractController: Controller
{
        protected AbstractController(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            var someIdClaim = accessor.HttpContext?.User?.Identities.First().Claims
                    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Type == "some_id");

           if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(someIdClaim)) 
           // respond with bad request and dont attach to corresponding action method
        }
}
```

Using asp net core 7.

There will be several controllers that will be deriving from this controller.

Obviously, this check could be in a middleware or something too. I just need this check to run for controllers that derive from this abstract controller.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your code and question. `protected ControllerThatUsesTenantId(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)` is a constructor, you can't return anything from a constructor ...  And the constructor should probably be named the same as the class it is contained in ...

Comment: updated for clarity

Comment: The general answer is the same: You cannot return anything from a constructor. Thats not possible in C#. What you maybe can do is throw some exception in the construtor and create a general exception handler that will then create the appropriate response to the client. But I've never used asp.net, so I can't help you with how to do that in detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could maybe help you more if you give more details about WHY are you trying to do this.

### Best solution (with some assumptions):

Assuming that what you want is to always ensure that your requests contain a specific claim, and return a Bad Request otherwise, I'd say that the best option is to use a [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) or a [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
Use a filter if you want to apply this only to specific endpoints or controllers, with an attribute. Use a middleware if ALL your endpoints should behave like this.

The filter would look like this:

```
public class RequiredClaimFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        string? someIdClaim = context.HttpContext.User.Identities.First().Claims.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Type == "some_id")?.Value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(someIdClaim))
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(400);
        }
    }
}
```

And you would apply it like this:

```
[RequiredClaimFilter]
public class AbstractController : ControllerBase
```

### Hackish solution:

As said in a comment, you can't return anything from a constructor. What you can do, though, is to **throw an exception**. That, by default will result in a 500 response (internal server error), would that meet your requirements?

However I'd say that generally speaking this is a bad approach, since you are telling the client that you made an error (500) while in fact the claim that you are checking makes me think that the request contained an error (and thus the response should be a 40x, as you proposed in your question).

Comment: So if I create a authorization filter and put the attribute on the abstract base controller, it will run for every deriving controller?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, if this is the only reason for you to derive from `AbstractController`, I mean if there is no more common behavior in `AbstractController`, I'd say it's clearer to get rid of it, and simply use the filter attribute in any controller where you want this behavior.

Comment: I actually need to use that field in many requests. So, I figured I would derive from a common controller that would have the sole purpose of checking and setting that field.

Comment: I've added some code example with a very basic implementation of the filter approach.